# how to create a unique key for caching query in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I used repository in a project that caching all queries.

there's a BaseRepository.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;

class BaseRepository implements BaseRepositoryInterface{
    protected $model;
    protected int $cacheDuration = 600; //per seconds
    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        return $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function paginate(int $paginate,string $cacheKey)
    {
        return Cache::remember($cacheKey,$this->cacheDuration , function () use ($paginate) {
            return $this->model->latest()->paginate($paginate);
        });
    }
    // other methods ...
}
```

then i used this repository in my service

PostService:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\App;

class PostService{
    public PostRepositoryInterface $postRepository;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postRepository = App::make(PostRepositoryInterface::class);
    }
    public function paginate(int $paginate, string $cacheKey)
    {
        return $this->postRepository->paginate($paginate,$cacheKey);
    }
}
```

finally i using the PostService in my controller

PostController:

```
class PostController extends Controller{

    public PostService $postService;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->postService = App::make(PostService::class);
    }

    public function index()
    {
        string $cacheKey = "posts.paginate";
        return $this->postService->paginate(10);
    }
}
```

the index method will return top 10 latest record correctly. now i need to create a unique CacheKey for all Repository queries. for example

TableName concat FunctionName // posts.paginate

so i can use this code into all method of Repository

```
public function paginate(int $paginate)
{
    $cacheKey = $this->model->getTable().__FUNCTION__;
    return Cache::remember($cacheKey,$this->cacheDuration , function () use ($paginate) {
        return $this->model->latest()->paginate($paginate);
    });
}
```

this is fine. but the problem is that this code repeat in all the method of this class.
if i use this code in another class, method name's will be incorrect.
What do you suggest to prevent duplication of this code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can easily use magic method in this way:

```php
class CacheService {
    private const $cacheableMethods = ['paginate'];
    private $otherSerivce;
    public __construct($otherSerivce) {
       $this->otherSerivce = $otherSerivce;
    }

    public __get($method, $args) {
        if(!in_array($method, static::$cachableMethods)) {
          return $this->otherSerivce->{$method}(...$args);
        }

        return Cache::remember(implode([$method, ...$args], ':'), function () {
            return $this->otherSerivce->{$method}(...$args);
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: this code has many errors. please test it once then edit

Comment: I put it as pseudocode; if you want to use it, you have to change it!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by passing function name to another class

I created CacheKey class:

```
class CacheKey{

    public static function generate(Model $model, $functionName):string
    {
        return $model->getTable()."_".$functionName;
    }
}
```

Then in any method of repository we can use this helper class as follows:

```
$cacheKey = CacheKey::generate($this->model,__FUNCTION__);
```